# How to calculate total sum of orientation changes in 6 DOF data from a Motion tracker?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics

I'm using data from a motion tracker that give provides 6 coordinates for every frame ( with frame rate of 240Hz)

Position: x, y, z

Orientation: azimuth(yaw), elevation(pitch), roll

I can calculate total distance travelled by sensor by the sum of the following equation at every frame

√(x2 − x1)^2 + (y2 − y1)^2 + (z2 − z1)2

I am interested in calculating the total number of orientation changes, analogous to distance travelled but for orientation data. I have seen the following orientation vector being used:

(x+cos(yaw)cos(pitch),y −cos(pitch)sin(yaw),z+sin(pitch))

can I use these orientation coordinates like I did with the position coordinates to calculate a meaningful metric for the sum of orientation changes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry, I fear I do not have the exact vocabulary to express my question precisely. I'm using a motion tracker attached to person's hands and coming up with metrics to describe the hand motion. I am currently using the total distance travelled by the sensor during one trial. I wanted a metric that could describe the total change in attitude or orientation.